# Unable to create Date from string in Safari

Tags: javascript, date, safari

I just want to create a js date object from a given string.

Stringformat: `yyyy,mm,dd`
This is my script:

```
var oDate = new Date('2013,10,07');
console.log(oDate);
```

In Chrome, IE and FF I get a right date, but with Safari I just get `NaN`.

Comment: What is `var_dump`? I don't seem to have it defined.

Comment: @icedwater I meant `console.log`. `var_dump` is for php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Date` constructor:

```
new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
```

You can fix this problem like this:

```
var s='2013,10,07';
var a = s.split(',');
var date = new Date(a[0],a[1]-1,a[2]);
```

But you must be sure that the date format is always the same as in your sample.

Comment: Yep, the format is always the same. Thanks for your solution. You just need to subtract 1 from the month value, cause month begins with 0 -> `new Date(a[0],a[1]-1,a[2]);`